# RSS feed reader does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, google-feed-api

I have a problem with loading RSS feed from the following URL

```
http://solutions.astrology.com/scripts/it.dll?cust_id=aamfha&doc=daily07short/dailyshort.xml
```

I am using the following code to read it:

```
url = 'http://solutions.astrology.com/scripts/it.dll?cust_id=aamfha&doc=daily07short/dailyshort.xml';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=4&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(){
    alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
    },
    success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
    }});
```

This code works fine for other links like to load RSS data like below

```
http://www.nbcnewyork.com/news/local/?rss=y&types=Article,Blog+Post&taxi=y
```

but it does not work for the link at the top and returns an error:

```
"Feed could not be loaded."
```

Can anybody help me with this? Or maybe suggest another API which can help to access these feeds.

I am accessing cross domain data. Also if you can suggest some better API or way to access cross domain RSS feeds data.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL doesn't return a valid rss feed. It's XML, but not RSS/Atom. See [W3C Feed Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/feed/).